# How to compare timestamps interval on Oracle SqlDeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two columns of type `timestamp(6)` in my table.

I want to find all the rows in the table where the time between these two timestamps is greater than 300 days. How do I write the `WHERE` clause of my SQL statement?

I want to write something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  timestamp1 - timestamp2 > 300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
WHERE (column1 - column2) > numtodsinterval( 300, 'day' )
```